# base grails 3.3.8 app demolishes heroku memory limit

Tags: heroku, grails, grails-3.3.x

I am trying to write a simple grails 3.3.8 app that I would like to deploy to heroku.

I started with a simple grails app:

```
$ grails create-app example
```

I then added a Procfile:

```
web: ./gradlew bootRun -Dgrails.server.port=$PORT
```

And a stage task to `build.gradle`:

```
task stage(dependsOn: assemble)
```

I figure that this app does nothing, and therefore should not stress a 512M heroku dyno, however:

```
2018-11-05T02:43:28.390592+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-11-05T02:43:32.587318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=729M(142.5%)
2018-11-05T02:43:32.587564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2018-11-05T02:43:36.536505+00:00 app[web.1]: :buildProperties
2018-11-05T02:43:37.378484+00:00 app[web.1]: :processResources
2018-11-05T02:43:37.381277+00:00 app[web.1]: :classes
2018-11-05T02:43:37.403505+00:00 app[web.1]: :findMainClass
2018-11-05T02:43:37.519404+00:00 app[web.1]: :bootRunPicked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-11-05T02:43:54.618402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=1164M(227.5%)
2018-11-05T02:43:54.618533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2018-11-05T02:43:54.618676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-11-05T02:43:54.788397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-11-05T02:43:54.804734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bootRun` is for running and developing locally. Its optimized for quick development, not for running in production.

To run in production you would normally run

```
./gradlew assemble
# Deploy build/libs/app.jar(or war) to your server
java -jar app.jar
```

There are many more ways to run a spring-boot/grails apps, for example deploying to tomcat or other servlet containers.

Comment: I also had to change my `Procfile` to `web: java -jar -Dserver.port=$PORT build/libs/*.war`